# How Does Voltmeter Sense/Measure All Potential Differences Present in an Electrochemical Cell?

Tags: electrochemistry

Voltmeter is an instrument which measures electric potential difference between two points.

When measuring electrode potential of some redox system (vs SHE for example), it is said that voltmeter reading contains sum of all potential differences present in a cell. This includes all electrode/electrolyte potential differences, contact potential differences between electrodes and probes of voltemter and possibly liquid junction potential. Probes of voltmeter are connected with two electrodes in a cell.

However, since voltmeter measures potential difference between two points, how can it sense sum of all potential differences in a cell if it is connected only between two electrodes and not all potential differences are created at these two points?

Comment: In addition to the answer by @Poutnik, you might also look into three and four wire potentiostats. They can be a bit hard to fathom, but they are part of electrochemistry’s common instrumentation.

Comment: @EdV These devices are indeed interesting, but they are still kind of like separation of two quarks ( leading to 2 quark doubles ). Advantage is some of the potential differences can be considered in this case constant and some  variable.

Comment: @Poutnik No problem: I already upvoted your answer.

Comment: Yes, I think I need to check how voltage devices work as I thought they can measure only potential differences between two points on which they are in direct electronic contact. I will check potenciostats as well.

Comment: What is strange to me is that as far as I know measuring potential difference between two points is done so that you take a voltmeter and connect these two points to voltmeter in parallel. I am not sure how can voltmeter measure all these potential differences in a cell with only two probes.

Comment: It does not measure "all these", it measures their sum, like if you would measure summary potential difference on e.g.  a serie of resistors, which were integrated in a single package ( for the sake of example ). The cell can be formally simulated by an integrated circuit, including variable voltage source, current dependent resistors and potential difference dependent capacitors.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but are you familiar with Kirchhoff’s voltage law? There is an article in wikipedia on Kirchhoff’s circuit laws.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the 2nd Kirchoff's law which expresses the fact that electrostatic field is conservative. Circulation of electrostatic field is always zero. Voltmeter does measure a sum, yes. If I wanted to measure a voltage on series of 3 resistors for example, I would need to connect a voltmeter on start of 1st resistor and the end of 3rd resistor. If I wanted to measure every resistor independently, I would adjust it accordingly. In any case I need to connect voltmeter on two points between which I want to know what voltage is

Comment: In a cell, we connect voltmeter on two electrodes and how is it that it doesn't read only voltage between metal electrodes and not all other potential differences. It would not be of much help if I connected voltmeter on some resistor and it includes a voltage on some other resistor as well in the reading.

Comment: Quite frankly, I cannot see why this is puzzling you. If you put the voltmeter leads on the terminals of an ordinary automobile battery, just to pick an example, you get a measurement that well approximates the battery’s open circuit voltage. The chemistry is happening inside, but so what? It is a black box, as it were, and could be replaced with its Thevenin equivalent in that regard.

Comment: Yes, but saying that something is a black box doesn't help in understanding of what happens inside.

Comment: True, but also, in some sense, perfectly fine: the voltmeter doesn’t care what is in the black box. All it can do is what you stated at the beginning: measure the potential difference between the two places contacted by the voltmeter’s electrodes. I once saw someone get less than 12 V from a 12 V automobile battery by screwing a wood screw into the side of the battery! Astoundingly bad and dangerous idea on multiple levels. But they figured if they put the screw halfway between the ends, they would get about 6 V. Then their voltmeter gave a measurement of about 6 V. It did not care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127681/discussion-between-dario-miric-and-ed-v).

Answer (score 2):

It is the topic for electronics, as measuring of electrochemistry related potential differences by a voltmeter is not different to measuring other potential differences. In both cases they are potentials of different pieces of conductor.

Potential of the wire connected to SHE is conventionally taken as the zero potential.

Even in pure electronics, all what a voltmeter measures is the sum of potential differences across all the circuit path from one measuring point to the other one. That includes all kinds of intended or parasitic components of the circuit. It is the same as for circuits involving electrochemical cell.

There is a close parallel, as you e.g. cannot in general directly measure potential differences inside enclosed integrated circuits.

Partial potential differences within the cell are not measurable this way, must be measured indirectly ( e.g.by analysis the cell behaviour under the load ) , or differently, or estimated theoretically.